# Creating user accounts with Puppet?

Tags: puppet, users, puppetmaster

I'm just getting started with Puppet and I have the following code in my test site.pp file:

```
class { 'account': {
  'danny':
     home_dir => '/home/danny',
     groups   => [ 'sudo', 'users' ],
     password => 'password'
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the [account](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/torrancew/account) module from Puppet Forge. I have checked that the module is installed correctly.

The error given when using the above code is:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:12 on node testpuppet.domain.io
>       Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>       Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Line 12 of site.pp is:

```
class { 'account': {
```

The documentation gives the following example:

```
account { 
  'sysadmin':
    home_dir => '/opt/sysadmin',
    groups   => [ 'sudo', 'users' ],
    ssh_key  => 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfQmMkvtWRnwas3DIti9qAuSFQXKcE0kdp5f42PP8l2kTytJPPWp5T/q8PXDQ2d2X5KplMCMDiUQkchqhmDp840jsqBQ9iZPejAjv3w2kITgScFNymAcErtzX52iw4lnUyjZzomCW8G3YthQMaRm2NkI4wcVcjzq+SKyTfzrBoH21RgZlfcx+/50AFRrarpYqel9W5DuLmmShHxD8clPS532Z/1X+1jCW2KikUhdo98lxYTIgFno05lwFOS9Ry89UyBarn1Ecp1zXpIBE7dMQif3UyLUTU9zCVIoZiJj4iO5lemSSV0v8GL97qclBUVJpaCpc4ebR7bhi0nQ28RcxQ==',
    comment   => 'SysAdmin user',
}
```

all the other modules that I'm using are within a class, such as the NTP module:

```
class { 
  '::ntp': 
  servers => [ 
    '0.uk.pool.ntp.org', 
    '1.uk.pool.ntp.org', 
    '2.uk.pool.ntp.org', 
    '3.uk.pool.ntp.org' 
  ], 
}
```

What would the correct syntax be to use the account module?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can name your classes as you want, but you need to use the right name for resources. In this case, the resource you want to use is `user`.

There is a very simple way to know how a resource should look:

```
$ puppet resource user dawud
user { 'dawud':
  ensure  => 'present',
  comment => 'David Sastre Medina,,,',
  gid     => '1001',
  groups  => ['sudo', 'audio', 'src', 'video', 'libvirt'],
  home    => '/home/dawud',
  shell   => '/bin/bash',
  uid     => '1001',
}
```

That code, inside a class would look:

```
class foo {
   user { 'dawud':
      ensure  => 'present',
      comment => 'David Sastre Medina,,,',
      gid     => '1001',
      groups  => ['sudo', 'audio', 'src', 'video', 'libvirt'],
      home    => '/home/dawud',
      shell   => '/bin/bash',
      uid     => '1001',
    }
}
```

Puppetlabs have a very good documentation on the [resource abstraction layer](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ral.html), RAL for short.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no puppet whiz, but you have an unmatched `{` in your sample. You have one open brace for `class` and another for `account`, but you only ever close the account brace.